# Creating new database code first when project contains migrations

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an EF6 project that is supposed to create its own database. So in the constructor of the database context, I set the Initializer

```
Database.SetInitializer<AudmDatabaseContext>(new AudmDatabaseInitializer());
```

AudmDatabaseInitializer is a class of type System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists that implements my seed method to fill some default data after creation.

I found that if I open a new context and try accessing some data, the DB would automatically be created, so my program can be started with a special parameter that creates a new db. That parameter triggers this bit of code

```
using (var db = new AudmDatabaseLib.Model.AudmDatabaseContext())
{
     if (!db.Database.Exists())
     {
          bool created = db.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
     }
}
```

And here's the weird thing: this works perfectly as long as my project contains no migrations. If there's any migrations present, the migrations start to be executed.. and of course they fail because there's no database. If I remove the migration .cs files (Configuration.cs can be left.. it seems to have no impact), then things work as expected, and then upon the first regular normal run, the migrations are performed.

It seems that in case there are migrations, those come first.. even though I see that db.Database.CreateIfNotExists is being executed, so I know it knows the DB isn't there and executing migrations make no sense.

Here's my migration config btw

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    ContextKey = "AudmDatabaseLib.AudmDatabaseContext";
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

How can I ensure that the DB creation runs prior to the automatic migrations? Or is there a way to temporarily disable automatic migrations before I call CreateIfNotExists?